# Dynamically casting base type to derived type. Non virtual functions called but virtual functions cause segmentation fault

Tags: c++, casting, virtual

Here is the simplified form of my code

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
  public:
  void func1() 
  {
    std::cout<<"In base func1"<<std::endl;
  }
  void func2()  
  {
    std::cout<<"In base func2"<<std::endl;
  }

  virtual void func4()
  {
    std::cout<<"In base func4"<<std::endl;
  }

  virtual void func5()
  {
    std::cout<<"In base func5"<<std::endl;
  }
};

class derived : public base
{
  public:
  void func1()
  {
    std::cout<<"In derived func1"<<std::endl;
  }

  void func3()
  {
    std::cout<<"In derived func3"<<std::endl;
  }

  void func5() 
  {
    std::cout<<"In derived func5"<<std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  derived* ptr = dynamic_cast<derived*>(new base());

  if(ptr == NULL)
  {
    std::cout<<"Cast failed"<<std::endl;
  }

  ptr->func1();
  ptr->func2();
  ptr->func3();
  ptr->func4();
  ptr->func5();

  delete ptr;
}
```

Dynamically casting a base object to derived type gives back a NULL pointer. This should lead to segmentation fault at ptr->func1(). My output however is

```
Output:
Cast failed
In derived func1
In base func2
In derived func3
```

The code crashes when ptr->func4() tries to execute. 
If the pointer is NULL, then access to any function, either virtual or non virtual should give a segmentation fault. Can someone explain the difference in treating the two types.

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to see the code that crashes. Forgot to take my crystal ball with me ;-)

Comment: "If the pointer is NULL, then access to any function, either virtual or non virtual should give a segmentation fault" - *Nowhere* in the standard is that claim warranted. The standard proclaims such a dereference invokes *undefined behavior*. That said, would you like to know how this could *appear* to "work"?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WhozCraig and  _@Kerrek SB_ Questionable though why `dynamic_cast<>` failed at all, isn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, why? `base` is not a `derived`? (Note the `new base()`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Silly me ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Very easy to expect one kind of problem even though another is present :-) My own first thought was that there's a `delete` through a base without virtual destructor, just because for some reason that's the first problem I suspect in polymorphic class design...

Comment: @WhozCraig, why do func1, func2 and func3 appear to work?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, i didnt add the virtual destructor on purpose, to keep the problem simple

Comment: @PranavKapoor So I agree with Kerrek, asking about undefined behavior is pretty much useless. It has nothing to do with `virtual` destructor. You try to `dynamic_cast<>` from a plain base instance. That doesn't work.

Comment: @PranavKapoor One way it could *appear* to work (though the behavior is still totally UB): You're a C++ compiler. You have a pointer that claims it refers to something *valid*, and you have a **non-virtual** member function needing to be called. Being non-virtual, no need to generate a vtable-lookup to get the proper member fn ptr. Just push the `this` (the value of the pointer, which is still `NULL`) and invoke a function call. You're not actually doing *anything* with the object you think is still working in those members. You're just sending a non-related string to a non-related `stdout`.

Comment: @PranavKapoor in other words, add a member variable to that `base` class and try to set/get something to/from it in those "working" member calls. You will *likely* be pleasantly rewarded with the crash-and-burn you seek. Still no guarantees. it is, after all, still UB.

Comment: @WhozCraig, so are you saying that the call to func1() is not leading to 'crash-and-burn' as the 'this' pointer is never dereferenced?

Comment: base* b; b->func1; Does the following code not 'crash-and-burn' for the same reason?

Comment: @PranavKapoor I'm saying that *may* be why it *appears* to work. *Defined* behavior and *Observed* behavior are *not* necessarily synonymous, and the graveyard of inexplicable buggy software is filled to over-capacity with software written by authors that assumed they were so. If you sent a trivial example (even more so than yours) through to assembly-output and examined the code generated you will *likely* see what I described ([trivial example](http://ideone.com/oiuu9M)).

Answer (score 4):

Your claim,

> This should lead to segmentation fault at `ptr->func1()`.

is entirely unsubstantiated and indeed wrong. There is no "segmentation fault" in the C++ language, and there is nothing that guarantees any kind of crash in the event of *undefined behaviour*, which is what you have. The behaviour of your program is simply not defined by the C++ language. This is not the same as being defined to crash.

Answer (score 1):

[Kerrek SB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427327/1413395) is a 100% right.

To give you a bit more insight why the `dynamic_cast<derived*>` failed in 1st place, you should note that a `base` instance simply isn't a `derived`. A better example for valid dynamic casting code would probably be:

```
base* b = new derived();
derived* ptr = dynamic_cast<derived*>(b);
```

That's what `dynamic_cast<>` is actually purposed for. You can't make an already existing instance of `base` miraculously change it's type to a `derived` using a `dynamic_cast<>`, it has to be an instance of this type already.